# Exist some lib to play ogg songs with speed changed?

Tags: ruby, audio, sdl, ogg

I'm doing a application in [Ruby/SDL](http://www.kmc.gr.jp/~ohai/rubysdl.en.html) to run only on Windows and I need to play OGG files (or some thing similar, like MP3) with speed changed, where I can specify how much faster or slower the song should be played. It need to be done without save the audio file and it have to allow me to play more than one music at the same time too.

Exist it to Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lib for many formats (including file perverts =) ) called FMOD. And there are ports of [libvorbis](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/vorbis/) and [FMOD](http://rubygems.org/gems/fmod) to ruby (see links).

Hope this would help!